Short generators of non-elementary subgroups of hyperbolic groups
In a project I am working on I need to find a pair of elements $a,b$ of a one-ended $\delta$-hyperbolic group $G$ such that the subgroup $\langle a,b \rangle$ is not virtually cyclic. Since the group $G$ is one-ended, and therefore not virtually cyclic, such pair must exist. I am interested in putting an upper bound on their length.
Question: suppose that $G = \langle S \mid R\rangle$ is a one-ended $\delta$-hyperbolic group, what is the smallest possible $N$ (in terms of $|S|$, $|R|$, and $\delta$) such that there exist elements $a,b \in B_G(1,N)$ such that the elements $a, b, ab, ab^{-1}$ are all of infinite order and the subgroup $\langle a,b \rangle \leq G$ is not virtually cyclic?
I was able to show that in a $\delta$-hyperbolic group one can use the size of a ball of radius $K \delta$ (the constant $K$ depends on which definition of $\delta$-hyperbolicity is used - slim/thin triangles, Gromov product...) as an upper bound on the maximal order of an element, and then write down a set of (in)equations over $G$, whose solutions are pairs of elements that don't generate virtually cyclic subgroups, then use the Ciobanu-Elder algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.09591) to get an upper bound on the word-length of the solutions. What I get is exponential in the size of the ball of radius $K\delta$, giving me an upper bound that is doubly exponential in $\delta$.
So I guess my updated question is: can I do better than $2^{|S|^{K\delta}}$?

From experience of similar problems, I suspect that this is difficult. Wouldn't this question be more suitable for MathOverflow?

Did you check the literature on uniform exponential growth in hyperbolic groups? The main argument in such proofs is finding short generators of rank 2 free subgroups. (Or free subsemigroup which suffices for your purposes.)
